# How to display the physical path of a web application using appcmd.exe?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, appcmd

Please, observe:

```
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop> $a
C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop> &$a list app "MyDayforce/" /text:*
APP
  path:"/"
  APP.NAME:"MyDayforce/"
  APPPOOL.NAME:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
  SITE.NAME:"MyDayforce"
  [application]
    path:"/"
    applicationPool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
    enabledProtocols:"http"
    serviceAutoStartEnabled:"false"
    serviceAutoStartProvider:""
    preloadEnabled:"false"
    [virtualDirectoryDefaults]
      path:""
      physicalPath:""
      userName:""
      password:""
      logonMethod:"ClearText"
      allowSubDirConfig:"true"
    [virtualDirectory]
      path:"/"
      physicalPath:"C:\Dayforce\SharpTop\UI\MyWORKBits"
      userName:""
      password:""
      logonMethod:"ClearText"
      allowSubDirConfig:"true"
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop> &$a list app "MyDayforce/" /text:applicationPool
Clr4IntegratedAppPool
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop> &$a list app "MyDayforce/" /text:enabledProtocols
http
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop>
```

I have no idea how to display the value of `physicalPath`. Tried all kinds of variants - nothing works.

So, how do I fetch the `physicalPath` from the app object ?

P.S.

I know how to do it from the vdir object:

```
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop> &$a list vdir /app.name:"MyDayforce/" /text:physicalPath
C:\Dayforce\SharpTop\UI\MyWORKBits
PS C:\Dayforce\DayforceRTQA\150520_747\SharpTop>
```

But I have a specific interest in the app object in order to understand whether nested properties can be fetched using the `/text` flag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good afternoon mark!

To display the physical path using only the app object you can reference it using the `[path='string']` syntax. Using this you can reference all of the properties of the nested `VirtualDirectory` object.

So for your example you would use the following command:
`&$a list app "MyDayforce/" /text:[path='/'].physicalPath`

Or more generally for default IIS installations

`C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app "Default Web Site/" /text:[path='/'].physicalPath`

Comment: Thank you very much. Could not figure it out. Do you happen to have a link to the respective documentation? Those pages I read about appcmd are very superficial and do not explain it.

Comment: Sorry, I wish that I did have a link. I determined this solution a while ago during troubleshooting I was doing for a separate problem. I couldn't find anything but the Microsoft provided documentation as well :(

Comment: How list apps: ***name, appPool and path*** ?

Comment: **IMPORTANT** it seems the `/text` paramneeds to be enclosed in quotes and when it is not:
`ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].`

i.e. `&$a list app "MyDayforce/" "/text:[path='/'].physicalPath"`